# Daterangepicker contar días excluyendo fines de semana y holidays

Tags: javascript, html5

Buen día compañeros,

Estoy trabajando con el daterangepicker y ya tengo desactivados los fines de semana y holidays de méxico en el calendario, y tengo una función que cuenta los días hábiles seleccionados con una fecha de inicio y fecha final, excluyendo los fines de semana pero ahora quiero que si se atraviesa un holiday en la selección de fecha no lo cuente, este es mi código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    start = document.getElementById("from");
    end = document.getElementById("to");
    diff = document.getElementById("solicitados");

    fecha = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(5*24*60*60*1000));

    var holiday = ["07/06/2018", "13/06/2018"];

    $(function () {

        $('input[name="from"]').daterangepicker({
            minDate: fecha,
            autoClose: true,
            singleDate: true,
            showShortcuts: false,
            singleMonth: true,
            autoUpdateInput: false,
            locale: {
                cancelLabel: 'Clear'
            }, dateLimit: {
                "days": <%=limite%>
                }, 
            isInvalidDate: function (date) { return date.day() == 0 || date.day() == 6 || holiday.indexOf(date.format('DD/MM/YYYY')) > -1}
        });

        $('input[name="from"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
            start.value = picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            end.value = picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY');          

            var a = moment([picker.startDate.format('YYYY'), picker.startDate.format('M'), picker.startDate.format('D')]);
            var b = moment([picker.endDate.format('YYYY'), picker.endDate.format('M'), picker.endDate.format('D')]);


            function workingDays(dateFrom, dateTo) {
                var from = moment(dateFrom, 'DD/MM/YYY'),
                  to = moment(dateTo, 'DD/MM/YYY'),
                  days = 0;

                while (!from.isAfter(to)) {
                    // Si no es sabado ni domingo
                    if (from.isoWeekday() !== 6 && from.isoWeekday() !== 7 && from.isoWeekday() !== holiday ) {
                        days++;
                    }
                    from.add(1, 'days');
                }
                return days;
            }

            var days = workingDays(start.value, end.value);
            diff.value = days;
        });

        $('input[name="from"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
            $(start).val('');
            $(end).val('');
        });

    });
</script>
```

¿Cómo puedo agregar en esta condición los holidays?

```
if (from.isoWeekday() !== 6 && from.isoWeekday() !== 7 && from.isoWeekday() !== holiday )
```

Sé que una vez resolviendo esto será de mucha ayuda para muchos, muchas gracias desde ya.

Comment: Mira a ver si la respuesta que propongo te vale, PD: buena pregunta :).

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre una posible solución a ese problema, el array de holiday, en vez de tener strings, que lo que recoja sean moments en el mismo formato que el resto de fechas:

`var holiday = [moment(AQUI LA FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYY'), moment(AQUI LA FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYY'), (...), moment(AQUI LA FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYY')];`

Y hacer la siguiente comparación:

```
 if (from.isoWeekday() !== 6 && from.isoWeekday() !== 7 && $.inArray(from,holiday) == -1)
```

Por lo visto:

`$.inArray(value,array[,fromIndex])` es una [función de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) (lo acabo de descubrir yo también xD), que busca en un array un valor concreto y su funcionamiento es similar al del `indexOf`, devuelve `-1` si no lo encuentra en el array, lo que en este caso se traduciría como: si la fecha que se compara no corresponde con ningún valor del array, la función devolverá `-1`, en caso contrario devolverá el índice del array donde se encuentra dicho valor.

*Espero que te sirva :)*

Comment: La primera parte no sé realmente si hace falta, pero por asegurar, es recomendable.

Comment: Acabo de probar pero en el conteo no ignora el holiday, si selecciono 3 días y uno es holiday me sigue contando 3 y no 2, intente poner el moment con fecha en el array pero no lee la fecha.